# Is it possible to suppress Binder Error: Could not find key in duckDB

Tags: sql, struct, duckdb

When querying for a field that is not part of the struct in duckDB you get the following error. Is it possible to suppress this error and return NULL?

Current behaviour:

```sql
SELECT a.b 
FROM 
    (SELECT {'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z': 3} AS a);
```

> Error: Binder Error: Could not find key "b" in struct
>
> Candidate Entries: "x", "y", "z"

Desired behaviour:

```sql
SELECT a.b 
FROM 
    (SELECT {'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z': 3} AS a);
```

```bash
┌───────┐
│   b   │
│ int32 │
├───────┤
│       │
└───────┘
```